# Program not responding when export more than 10000 data to csv. QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm exporting data to csv. I can export if datas around 8K or 10K but when I try to export data around 100K I get a warning "program not responding".

```
void MainWindow::exportArraysToCSV(QStringList labelList, QList < QList < double >> dataColums, QChar sep) {
  QString filters("CSV files (*.csv);;All files (*.*)");
  QString defaultFilter("CSVi files (*.csv)");
  QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0, "Save file", QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(),
    filters, & defaultFilter);
  QFile file(fileName);

  if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Append)) {
    QTextStream data( & file);
    QStringList strList;
    QString formula;

    foreach(auto label, labelList) {
      if (label.length() > 0){
          strList.append("," + label + ",");

      }

      else
        strList.append("");
    }

  data << strList.join(",") << "\n";

    int maxRowCount = 0;
    foreach(auto column, dataColums)
    maxRowCount = qMax(maxRowCount, column.count());

    for (int i = 5; i < maxRowCount; ++i) // rows
    {
      strList.clear();
      for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) // columns
      {
        if (i < dataColums[j].count())
          strList.append(QString::number(dataColums[j][i], 'f'));


        else
          strList.append("\"\" ");
      }

      data << strList.join(",") + "\n";


    }
    data << "=SUM(A2:A1255)";
    file.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Move your export to CSV to background thread, and pass QList and QStringList arguments by constant reference to prevent data copying.

Comment: If you do this in main thread, i.e. GUI thread, you stop program from responding. Simply don't do costy operations in main thread

Comment: Windows periodically sends a "ping" message to the program, to see that it is still alive. But when busy in in the loop, the program doesn't check its message queue, so appears to be "not responding" for a while.

Comment: So thats all I need wait untill finish loop?

Comment: The shown code does not appear to be written in C++, but in some weird language with a `foreach` statement, which does not exist in C++.

Comment: @BoP I waited around one hour but it didn't respond.